# Fancybox unique url inline content link

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, fancybox

I am looking to load a fancybox popup using a url, so upload load the fancybox pops up using:

www.mysite.com/index.html#hrefgoeshere

What would the script be?

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Kyle

***Update***

Thanks for everyones help!! Here is what ended up working great for me. I saved our my content into separate html files and then called them with fancybox.iframe

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
     'scrolling'   : 'no'   
    });
    if (window.location.hash !== "") {
        $(window.location.hash).click();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use the fancybox method i think it is safer  :

ex:

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
    $.fancybox({
        content: $(window.location.hash).html()
    });
});
```